# Need to archive data on successful cart transaction using Update SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to archive a product when it has been bought in the storefront. I`m thinking about doing a SQL JOIN but not sure...

Is this the query I need to run?

```
  UPDATE product 
  INNER JOIN cart on cart.product_id = product.id
  SET product.archive = 1
```

**cart**

```
id (int)
product_id (int)
quantity (int)
```

**product**

```
id (int)
name (varchar 45)
price (decimal 10,2)
quantity (int)
image (varchar 255)
archive (tinyint) default 0
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a situation where you'd you want to use a trigger. Everytime a new line is added in  the Cart table, it should update product.archive to 1 (or any other changes to the Product table).

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg
    AFTER INSERT ON Cart
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE Product
        SET archive = 1
        WHERE Product.id = NEW.product_id;
END $$
```

Please take into account that I'm new to MySQL and I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

### The update query

Let's examine this query closely

```
  UPDATE product 
  INNER JOIN cart on cart.product_id = product.id
  SET product.archive = 1
```

What does this query do? It archives every single product that has been placed into at least one user's cart. Surely that's not what you want? Your cart table does not have a user id in it. HOw do you determine which item in the cart belong to which user? Please consider adding such a column to your table.

### To archive or not to archive

Shouldn't a product be archived only when it's quantity reaches zero? but should it be archived at all? If you have an archive column in your table in each query you will need to have a clause that checks this flag

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE archive = 1   /* or 0 */
```

But this archive column can take only one of two values and that makes an index on that column completely useless. So as your data grows, your queries will become slower and slower.